# Rails belongs_to returning nil even though foreign key is valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations

### Summary

I'm running into an issue where my `belongs_to` association is returning `nil` when I don't think it should be.

### What I'm trying to do

A `ChannelUser` should be able to return the messages from the associated `channel` where the `created_at` is greater than the last time its `user` last read from this `channel`.  The class definitions follow:

```rb
class ChannelUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :channel
  belongs_to :user

  scope :with_channel, -> { includes(:channel) }

  def unread_messages
    channel.messages.where('created_at > ?', last_read_at)
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :channel_users, -> { includes(:channel) }, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :channels, through: :channel_users
  has_many :messages
end

class Channel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :channel_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :channel_users
  has_many :messages, -> { order(created_at: :asc).limit(100) }, dependent: :destroy
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :channel
  belongs_to :user
  has_rich_text :body
  ...
end
```

I'm trying to render a total number of unread messages from all channels a user has joined in the view:

```rb
<%= current_user.channel_users.sum(&:unread_messages) %>
```

The `User` class has `has_many :channel_users` and `has_many :channels, through: :channel_users`.  The `Channel` class has `has_many :channel_users` and `has_many :users, through: :channel_users`.

### Problem

When I execute the `unread_messages` method in the rails console with any `ChannelUser` instance, I don't get an error.  However, when I run the application in development, I get:

[image]

As you can see in the web-console at the bottom of the picture, `channel` returns `nil` even though `channel_id` is a valid foreign key.  In fact, the schema is defined as such:

```rb
class CreateChannelUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :channel_users do |t|
      t.belongs_to :channel, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :user, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I also put a breakpoint in the view with `<% debugger %>` and looked at the values for `current_user`, `current_user.channel_users`, and `current_user.channel_users.first.unread_messages`.  For `current_user`, I got the instance of `User` associated with my logged in account.  For `current_user.channel_users`, I got the records that represented the chat channels I've joined.  For `curretn_user.channel_users.first.unread_messages`, I do not get an error, I get an empty relation set, correctly identifying that I don't have any unread messages.  Important to note that this error does not occur when I do not aggregate for the sum of all unread messages.

#### Update

I found out I could change the scope of the web console by clicking the line in the call stack, so here is more output from the web console:

```
>> current_user.channel_users

=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ChannelUser id: 7, channel_id: 5, user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-11-09 06:42:52", updated_at: "2020-11-15 23:44:28", last_read_at: "2020-11-15 23:44:28">, #<ChannelUser id: 3, channel_id: 4, user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-11-09 06:26:12", updated_at: "2020-11-09 06:27:03", last_read_at: "2020-11-09 06:27:03">, #<ChannelUser id: 4, channel_id: 6, user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-11-09 06:30:41", updated_at: "2020-11-15 23:32:26", last_read_at: "2020-11-15 23:32:26">, #<ChannelUser id: 8, channel_id: 7, user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-11-10 01:20:44", updated_at: "2020-11-15 23:33:24", last_read_at: "2020-11-15 23:33:24">]>

>> current_user.channel_users.map(&:unread_messages)

NoMethodError: undefined method `messages' for nil:NilClass
    from /home/jakehockey10/Code/team-portal/app/models/channel_user.rb:29:in `unread_messages'
    from /home/jakehockey10/Code/team-portal/app/views/dashboard/show.html.erb:9:in `map'
    from /home/jakehockey10/Code/team-portal/app/views/dashboard/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_dashboard_show_html_erb___259171981150348787_116880'

>> current_user.channel_users.first.unread_messages

NoMethodError: undefined method `messages' for nil:NilClass
    from /home/jakehockey10/Code/team-portal/app/models/channel_user.rb:29:in `unread_messages'
    from /home/jakehockey10/Code/team-portal/app/views/dashboard/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_dashboard_show_html_erb___259171981150348787_116880'

>> current_user.channel_users.first

=> #<ChannelUser id: 7, channel_id: 5, user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-11-09 06:42:52", updated_at: "2020-11-15 23:44:28", last_read_at: "2020-11-15 23:44:28">

>> current_user.channel_users.first.channel

=> nil

>> Channel.find(5)

=> #<Channel id: 5, name: "general", account_id: 2, created_at: "2020-11-09 06:30:32", updated_at: "2020-11-09 06:30:32", direct_message: false>
```

That last one really baffles me.  Asking for the channel through the current_user's channel_users association, I get `nil`, but when I see that the channel_id is 5, and I ask for the channel with id 5 through `Channel`, I can find it just fine.  What gives?

#### Another thing I tried

I went ahead in the rails console and queried the same thing I'm after, and got no error:

```
> User.first.channel_users.sum(&:unread_messages)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ChannelUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "channel_users".* FROM "channel_users" WHERE "channel_users"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Channel Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "channels".* FROM "channels" WHERE "channels"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4)  [["id", 5], ["id", 4], ["id", 6], ["id", 7]]
  Message Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."channel_id" = $1 AND (created_at > '2020-11-15 23:44:28.787257') ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["channel_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 100]]
  Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."channel_id" = $1 AND (created_at > '2020-11-09 06:27:03.105358') ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["channel_id", 4], ["LIMIT", 100]]
  Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."channel_id" = $1 AND (created_at > '2020-11-15 23:32:26.070403') ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["channel_id", 6], ["LIMIT", 100]]
  Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."channel_id" = $1 AND (created_at > '2020-11-15 23:33:24.022821') ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["channel_id", 7], ["LIMIT", 100]]

=> []
```

#### Another update

Here is the icing on the cake:

[image]

I don't know what to make of this, and I'm wondering if it is some sort of name collision issue or something.  How do I diagnose this?

### Update

Same issue, trying different approaches:

[image]

Why in the world would it throw the error on this line, but then not throw the error if I paste the same line in the web-console on the error page?  What am I missing?

Comment: In the error console that is being triggered by `current_user.channel_users.sum(&:unread_messages)`, what do you get for values when you enter `current_user` and `current_user.channel_users`? And, in that same console, you could try `current_user.channel_users.first.unread_messages` and see if it breaks or works. If it works, then it feels like you might just have a data issue with one of your channel_users records. If they all fail like that, then might be good to actually see your `User` and `Channel` models in their entirety.

Comment: The problem with looking for `current_user` and `current_user.channel_users` in the model's instance method, `unread_messages`.  But if I put a debugger in the view instead of the console where I fail in the instance method, please see my updates to the question

Comment: The rails console does not fail with the same error, but with the same query.

Comment: This is fascintating. I've not seen the `scope :with_channel, -> { includes(:channel) }` and `, -> { includes(:channel) },`. I'd try deleting those. Does it work without them?

Comment: No same issue unfortunately 

Comment: my guess would be it's some combination of the includes in the association and the limit 100...  maybe try removing both of those things?  also what do the logs show for the sql queries that were run near the error (similar to the ones that you show for the console run of `User.first.channel_users.sum(&:unread_messages)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out the issue.  In this application, to provide multi-tenancy, each User has an associated Account.  Accounts can be personal or non-personal.  When logged in, you can change your perspective from your personal account to any non-personal accounts you are associated with as well.  Then, resources that have an `account_id` column are filtered to what the current account is.  This filtering happens in middleware, thus separate from the code doing the actual querying in question.

When I first started implementing this feature, I had created some Channels on my personal account before attempting to limit Channels, as a whole feature, to non-personal account contexts.  So there were some Channels in my database that were associated with personal accounts.

In my screenshots, the app is using that middleware to limit the channels to ones with the specific, current `account_id`.  But when I mimicked those same queries in the web-console or in rails console, there obviously wasn't a middleware running to filter to what the current account was because there was no current account in that context.  This explains why I kept seeing different results when running the app vs. running these queries in consoles.

Now that I have destroyed all Channels that were associated with personal accounts, the error is gone.  I've also added some validation to prevent this in the future:

```rb
class Channel < ApplicationRecord

  ...

  validate :account_not_personal

  private

  ...

  def account_not_personal
    errors.add(:account, 'Channels are only supported for non-personal accounts') if account&.personal?
  end
end
```

```rb
require 'test_helper'

class ChannelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'name is required' do
    channel = Channel.new(name: nil)
    assert_not channel.valid?
    assert_not_empty channel.errors[:name]
  end

  test 'account is required' do
    channel = Channel.new(account: nil)
    assert_not channel.valid?
    assert_not_empty channel.errors[:account]
  end

  test 'account should be non-personal' do
    channel = Channel.new(name: 'test', account: Account.new(personal: false))
    assert channel.valid?
  end

  test 'account cannot be personal' do
    channel = Channel.new(name: 'test', account: Account.new(personal: true))
    assert_not channel.valid?
    assert_not_empty channel.errors[:account]
  end
end
```

Comment: What was the final troubleshooting step that left you figure this out?

Comment: I remembered that I wanted this feature to only be available while logged into a non-personal account.  So I queried my database for channels that were associated with personal accounts to see if I had a data integrity problem.  Sure enough, there were records associated with personal accounts.  So I reminded myself of how the multitenancy worked in the app, and ran my query for unread messages and included a specific `where` on my non-personal `account_id` and saw where that `nil` was coming from.  I also used `explain` on the queries to remind me `account_id` was included implicitly

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `includes`, I'm not 100% sure, but it could be potential issue.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :channel_users, dependent: :destroy
```

You can replace `includes` in model with
`<%= current_user.channel_users.includes(:channel).sum(&:unread_messages) %>`

Comment: I've tried this with and without the use of includes, still same result. This is the strangest thing I've ever run into with rails

Answer (score 0):

Im 95% sure that the problem comes from the Message model !

***It seems like the channel.messages is not equal to channel.user.messages.***

**Firstly**, you didnt shown us the ***Message's model*** in your question, please update the question.

**Secondly**, you have tow models: Channel & User, and both of them has an ***association with the message model*** (`has_many :messages`), and for me this is not very well associated (I can not thing about the solution before seeing the Message's model).

**Thirdly**, in your query:

```
User.first.channel_users.sum(&:unread_messages)
```

A line of those:

```
Message Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."channel_id" = $1 AND (created_at > '2020-11-15 23:44:28.787257') ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["channel_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 100]]
  Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."channel_id" = $1 AND (created_at > '2020-11-09 06:27:03.105358') ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["channel_id", 4], ["LIMIT", 100]]
  Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."channel_id" = $1 AND (created_at > '2020-11-15 23:32:26.070403') ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["channel_id", 6], ["LIMIT", 100]]
  Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."channel_id" = $1 AND (created_at > '2020-11-15 23:33:24.022821') ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $2  [["channel_id", 7], ["LIMIT", 100]]
```

the first line for exemple, is something like:

```
Message Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."channel_id" = 5 AND (created_at > '2020-11-15 23:44:28.787257') ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" ASC LIMIT 100
```

Wich means: **get a 100 sorted messages having the channel_id = 5**. And this returned null ! or ***empty set of messages***.

So the problme, **FOR ME**, comes from there.

Comment: I updated my question with the Message model as you asked.

Channels have Messages because of the messages that any user sends to a channel.  Users have messages that are the messages they have sent.

In other words, each message has a user_id and channel_id on the record

Comment: the problem is there ... the channel.messages is not related to user.messages

Comment: can you tell me what you get by doing: channel.messages.first.user.channel .... and user.messages.first.channel.user ?

Comment: for the first one, I had to add `channel_user.` to the beginning, because I don't have a `channel` variable at this scope.  It failed miserably for the same error at the center of this post.  The second one doesn't make sense, unfortunately.  Channel's don't have a single user associated with them, they have many users associated with them.

Comment: More on the first one: `channel_user` has a valid `channel_id`.  But `channel_user.channel` returns `nil`.  This is again the central problem that I'm seeing and don't know how to diagnose/solve.

Comment: another fact: if I pull up the rails console, I don't see the error: > ChannelUser.find_by(channel_id: 5).channel
  ChannelUser Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "channel_users".* FROM "channel_users" WHERE "channel_users"."channel_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["channel_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Channel Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "channels".* FROM "channels" WHERE "channels"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Channel:0x00005645004da968 id: 5, name: "general", account_id: 2, created_at: Mon, 09 Nov 2020 06:30:32 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 09 Nov 2020 06:30:32 UTC +00:00, direct_message: false>

Comment: can you please do: ChannelUser.reflect_on_association(:channel) in order to see the class_name and inverse_of ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response: When I run `ChannelUser.reflect_on_association(:channel)`, `class_name` returns "Channel"  When I look up `inverse_of` I get `nil`.

Comment: I appreciate all the time you spent trying to help me diagnose this.  I apologize that this issue was due to an aspect of my application that was not mentioned in the question.